# Passed javascript variable inside php string

Tags: javascript, php

my javascript and php code run on server

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
  var content ='<p><?php echo "Helllo"; ?></p>';
</script>
```

it work but when i try passed a variable inside php tring:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var temp = 4444;
  var content ='<p><?php echo '+ temp +'; ?></p>';
</script>
```

it cant get temp variable;
i can echo temp variable in php code.
what wrong with my code
thank for help.

Comment: Start with this ^

Comment: And your solution is obviously `var content ='<p>' + temp + '</p>';`

Comment: php code is executed on the server and then sent to the browser along with the surrounding HTML and javascript. THEN the javascript is then ran by the browser,  so no, you can not print a PHP variable in javascript this way.